# JS Round Robin Cyclic Algorithm with array

Tags: javascript

I try to apply the algorithm from [this source](https://www.devenezia.com/javascript/article.php/RoundRobin2.html) to array like this:

```
function tournament (n) {
  let pairs = [];
  const k = n.length

  for (let r=1; r<k; r++) {
    for (let i=1; i <= k/2; i++) {
      if (i==1) {
        pairs.push([n[0], n[(k-1+r-1) % (k-1) + 2]]);
      } else
      pairs.push([n[(r+i-2) % (k-1) + 2], n[(k-1+r-i) % (k-1) + 2]]);
    }
  }
  
  return pairs
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tournament([1,2,3,4,5,6]), null, 2))
```

But some of pairs has null value in output. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is subtract 1 from each expression:

```
function tournament (n) {
  let pairs = [];
  const k = n.length

  for (let r=1; r<k; r++) {
    for (let i=1; i <= k/2; i++) {
      if (i==1) {
        pairs.push([n[1-1], n[(k-1+r-1) % (k-1) + 1]]);
      } else
      pairs.push([n[(r+i-2) % (k-1) + 1], n[(k-1+r-i) % (k-1) + 1]]);
    }
  }
  
  return pairs
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tournament([1,2,3,4,5,6]), null, 2))
```